# AgGrid RowData updated outside Angular component, needs rows to be redrawn

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am using `ag-grid-angular` in my Angular project.  My `app` component hold my main data model (`rowData`), and two sub components `grid` and `grid-details`.  The `grid` component has an `@Input` to bind to `rowData`, and holds the `ag-grid-angular` component which `rowData` is also bound to.  The `grid-detail` component also has an `@Input` to bind to the model and has a form in which `rowData` can be changed.

I have abstracted the application in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-schnpx)

When I change data in `ag-grid-angular` I can see the change in `rowData` in `app` and `grid-details`, implying correctly bound properties across the components.  When I change `rowData` in `grid-details`, I can see the change in `app` but the data presentation in `ag-grid-angular` is not updated.  When call on `gridApi` to redraw the rows, the data is correctly presented (implying that the data was also correctly bound as I didn't need to set the row data again in gridApi).

1. If all data is correctly bound, why does `ag-grid-angular` not refresh automatically?
2. What is an easy pattern to call `gridApi.redrawRows()`? I have multiple components in my actual implementation and would like some kind of catch all `onChange` rather than implement some `@Output` event emitter for each subcomponent.

What I have tried: I tried to implement a call to `gridApi.redrawRows()` via Angular's `OnChanges`, but I realise that `OnChanges` lifecycle hook is not called on value changes within the instance of `rowData`.  So in my situation `OnChanges` does not get called when I change data in `grid-details`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like normal Angular change detection behavior.

Presumably, your rowData variable is an array, and your are updating an item in the array.

However, for change detection to fire, you need to replace the instance of the array. So you could, for instance do something like

`this.rowData = [...this.rowData]`